# How to fix "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)"?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use var value in file.write function:

```
profile = open("/tmp/%s.pcf", 'w+') % uid
```

and I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'file' and 'str'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the string formatting operand to the string itself:

```
profile = open("/tmp/%s.pcf" % uid, 'w+')
```

You were trying to apply it to the result of the `open()` call, which is a file.

Answer (score 1):

You need the string format inside

```
profile = open("/tmp/%s.pcf" % uid, 'w+')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
profile = open("/tmp/%s.pcf" % uid, 'w+')
```